# Encrypt data with BCrypt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bcrypt

I’ve a web application (asp.net mvc) and I need to encrypt some data that will be stored in the database.
Since I’m using BCrypt for the user password, I was thinking on using it as well to encrypt other data… what do you think? Is BCrypt just for passwords or can I use it as well for other data? Or maybe there is a best way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to learn the difference between **hashing** and **encryption**.

Comment: Security is _hard_.  You need to learn a lot more about it before you can use encryption properly.  In particular, where will you store the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BCrypt does not encrypt anything.  It is a HASHING algorithm that uses Blowfish internally, but does not actually encrypt your data.

The main difference:

**Hashing** is an algorithm that takes data of variable size and generates a fixed-size representation of that data.  The original data, unless stored elsewhere, is lost AND cannot be retrieved.

**Encrypting** is an algorithm that takes data of variable size and generates a similarly-sized chunk of data.  The original data, unless stored elsewhere (thereby voiding the purpose of encryption), is lost.  It CAN, however, be retrieved.  The Encryption process uses a separate piece of data called a **Key**.  Provided the associated decryption algorithm is used, the same key will decrypt the data and the original information can be retrieved.

So:

Before anyone can answer your question, you must first understand what you are asking.  Do you, in fact, need to store *encrypted* information, or rather is it *hashed* information?  If you merely need to store sensitive information, but never need to return the original value back to the user, then continue using BCrypt, as it will **hash** your data (thereby making it unreadable, but still comparable).  If, on the other hand, you want to store sensitive information that you one day may need to supply to someone (for instance, a credit card number), then look into sql **encryption** algorithms.

As you explore the world of security, you will quickly find that it is very painful, but very important.  For instance: SLaks brings up a good point.  If you encrypt your data, somewhere, somehow, you need to store your key.  But if that key is found, then someone can steal all of your data!  You must find a way to properly encrypt your data while hiding the key from the public.  There are several ways of doing this; google around a bit before you commit to one, as it may not be as secure as you think.

Microsoft has some good recommendations: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345262.aspx

You did not specify what flavor of sql you are using, so a flavor-specific answer cannot be supplied.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and well worded answer. This helped me +1